# How to launch programatically a checkbox's on_change handler?

Tags: jquery

There is a `checkbox` :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cacher" />
...
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

        ...

        $('#cacher').on("change", function() {
            var deb = convertDateFormat3($("#date_deb_").val());
            var fin = convertDateFormat3($("#date_fin_").val());
            listeMvt.ajax.url("<?php echo RP_SSP; ?>server_processing_mvtcaisse.php?deb="+deb+"&fin="+fin).load(); // it reloads a datatable's data
        });
        // the next two lines dont work
        $("#cacher").prop("checked",true);
        $("#cacher").change();
        ...
});
</script>
```

On document ready I want the checkbox to be checked and consequently its on_change event launched , but the datatable's data is not changed ! So how to launch the checkbox's handler ?

Comment: Check the console for errors; what you have now should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well a better solution for this is as follows

```
var checkboxListener = function(){
     var deb = convertDateFormat3($("#date_deb_").val());
     var fin = convertDateFormat3($("#date_fin_").val());
     listeMvt.ajax.url("<?php echo RP_SSP; ?>server_processing_mvtcaisse.php?deb="+deb+"&fin="+fin).load(); // it reloads a datatable's data
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    ...

    $('#cacher').on("change", checkboxListener);
    checkboxListener();
}
```

Its not a good way to programmatically trigger an event. Even though you want to do it you can use `trigger` method like this

```
$('#cacher').trigger("change");
```

Comment: you are referencing a variable defined in document ready in the function so it wouldnt work !

Comment: @pheromix You mean this variable `listeMvt` if yes the OP hasn't mentioned anywhere that its defined inside the document ready function.

Comment: Anyway you can move `listeMvt` outside or you can move `checkboxListener` function inside document ready. it will work.

Comment: listeMvt is defined in document ready : `var listeMvt = $('#listeMvt').DataTable({ ... });`